# How to get current URL in a PHP image?

Tags: php, image

I want to get current URL inside a PNG generated by PHP (`header('Content-Type: image/png');`)

But when i use `http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`, 
The URL output is the file's location (http://test.com/png.php) but not the page which get the img with `<img>` tag.

What can i do to get current URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, not REQUEST_URI.

Comment: But when i use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it return back nothing

Comment: If you're loading the image directly by typing the URL to your script, that's because there is no referrer.  If you are loading it via an `<img>` tag on a web page, of course, then `echo`ing text will break the image, anyway.

Comment: My code is like `$url_full = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: FINAL CODE: `$url_full = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you, but I'll give it a go. If you serve an image via PHP, it's URL will always point to a PHP script. If you want it to look like it's really a .png image, you have 2 choices:

1) Create a rewrite rule which will redirect some .png URL to your PHP script and then serve that URL to users.

2) Stick with the current URL, but also add an (non-standard!) Content-Disposition header:

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_image.png"');`

This way the URL will still point to a PHP script, but when a user tries to save the image, the suggested name won't be the PHP script, but the name specified in Content-Disposition.

Comment: I do mot mean this. I mean i want to get current url which is `img src` ing this image.(Like http://test.com/123213 )

Comment: I don't understand you. Img src is an IMG HTML tag with an src attribute which holds the URL. The URL in the src attribute can hold a link to a PHP script without any problems, as long as the link returns a valid image.

Comment: Oh, yeah, then Ed's on the right track. You need the referrer. You could raise an error in the script which prints the referrer and look at the error log to see if everything is ok. Of course, you need to suppress error printing on output.